# How do I add checks to a function created using tidy eval framework?

Tags: r, tidyeval

Say I have created a function using the tidy eval framework -

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

my_function <- function(data, var){
    
    var_expr <- enquo(var)
    
    data %>% 
        group_by(!!var_expr) %>% 
        summarise(count = n()) %>% 
        ungroup()
}
```

When I run the following function, I get the result below it

```
my_function(mtcars, cyl)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl count
  <dbl> <int>
1     4    11
2     6     7
3     8    14
```

How do I add the following checks to this function -

1. Check if `data` is a dataframe. If not, return the error `data should be a dataframe`
2. Check if `var` is missing. If so return the error `var is missing`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the following modifications.

- In order to check if our input data is of a particular class we can check its class attribute and in this case whether it's a data frame or tibble they both contains the class `data.frame`
- Also for `missing` function, it is normally used inside many functions to check whether an argument is assigned a value so that they generate a value as the default value. In your case we can terminate the execution of the function (you can also check the source code of `length` function on how it specifies a value for `size` argument when it is missing)
- You can use `base::stop` in place of `rlang::abort` as specified by dear @akrun

```
library(rlang)

my_function <- function(data, var){
  if(!"data.frame" %in% attr(data, "class")) {
    abort("data should be a data frame")
  } 
  if(missing(var)) {
    abort("var is missing")
  }
  
  var_expr <- enquo(var)
  
  data %>% 
    group_by(!!var_expr) %>% 
    summarise(count = n()) %>% 
    ungroup()
}
```

**Special thanks** to dear **@27 ϕ 9** for bringing this valuable point to my attention. We can also customize the output error message in `stopifnot` function which is another way of checking your input arguments:

```
my_function <- function(data, var){
  stopifnot("The input data is not of class data frame" = "data.frame" %in% attr(data, "class") ,
            "var is missing" = !missing(var)) 
  
  var_expr <- enquo(var)
  
  data %>% 
    group_by(!!var_expr) %>% 
    summarise(count = n()) %>% 
    ungroup()
}
```

**Special thanks** to dear **@IceCreamToucan** for presenting yet another option which is using the `inherits` function in lieu of `attr`. In case the input data does not include `data.frame` in its class attributes it returns `FALSE`:

```
my_function <- function(data, var){
  if(!inherits(data, "data.frame")) {
    stop("data is not of class data.frame")
  } 
  
  if(missing(var)) {
    stop("var is missing")
  }
  
  var_expr <- enquo(var)
  
  data %>% 
    group_by(!!var_expr) %>% 
    summarise(count = n()) %>% 
    ungroup()
}
```

Comment: Or in `base R`, `stop` in place of `rlang::abort`

Comment: Exactly master. I saw the OP used `rlang` so I just go on with it. Not to mention I really like `rlang`.